# List of numbered pieces of text

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, theorems

To number short pieces of text throughout my report I used:

```
\newtheorem{SampleEnv}{}[section]
```

How do I generate a list of all the numbered pieces of text?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

A near universal solution to this is to use the [`thmtools` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools).  It provides a `\listoftheorems` command (compile your document twice to get this updated).

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}

\newtheorem{SampleEnv}{}[section] 

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems

\section{First section}    

Main text:

\begin{SampleEnv}
  Phrase One.
\end{SampleEnv}

Some text in between.

\begin{SampleEnv}
  Phrase Two.
\end{SampleEnv}

\end{document}
```

`thmtools` will also work in combination with `amsthm` or `ntheorem`.  The `ntheorm` package already provides such functionality.

Should you want a different title for this list you can something like

```
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of highlighted phrases}
```